# How to stop PDB from printing the last variable everytime

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

Given the following interactive session:

```
$ python -c "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()"
--Return--
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) print "hello"
hello
(Pdb)
hello
(Pdb)
hello
(Pdb) pass
(Pdb)
(Pdb)
```

The hello gets printed out on each new statement. Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "printing the last variable", it's repeating the last pdb command when you hit enter without specifying a command or python expression.

Why is this happening ? Well, because the authors thought it might be a useful shortcut so you don't have to keep on retyping 'n' or 's' over and over. [It's actually documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) FWIW:

> Entering a blank line repeats the last command entered. Exception: if the last command was a list command, the next 11 lines are listed.

As to the "how to stop it" part, I guess you'll have to either fork pdb or create your own debugger subclass, but I fail to see why you would do so - it's actually a rather useful feature for a debugger (would indeed be annoying for a shell but that's not what we're talking about here, are we ?).